# [MySql][PHP] Extract fathers/sons tree

Tags: php, mysql, tree, hierarchical

I have a db structure as in the image attached, where in column A I have fathers and in column B sons. As you see a son can also be a father. Now, I would like to know if there is a way through a single query mysql to select all the *infinite* hierarchical tree.

Thank you.

[image: Father/Sons db structure]

Comment: No you can not. You can create a very large self join... let's say a 10 self-join and create a table with 10 hierarchies. It would be FAR more optimal to simply SELECT the whole table and then use php to process the entire table then do a super large self join...

Comment: Do it in PHP, yes. 1 single query, probably can't

Comment: @ProfileTwist Yes, but how can I know how many sons has each son of "B"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a known way of doing this in MySQL with infinite levels. You could always use n self-joins, but using PHP is probably a better approach.

You can however restructure your db schema, for example using Pre Order Tree Traversal:

[Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/)

This will increase the complexity and runtime of inserting data, but will make it much easier to fetch a tree or subtree.